# SDL OpenGL app crashing in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, sdl, glew

i am having a weird problem with opengl in visualstudio where every opengl function points to NULL if i build the program in release mode.

i have tried glew and gl3w none of them work

glew/gl3w is initialized after the context is created and in debug mode it runs fine

the project settings are default i only included the include folders and the respective lib folders

did anybody have a similiar issue?

```
#include<SDL.h>
#include<GL\glew.h>
#include<assert.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_GLContext context;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    assert(!glewInit());

    GLuint id;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &id);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for downvoting on my post very helpful, btw im new

Comment: Please can you provide some more information - how are you loading GLEW/GL3W, what are your project settings, etc. If something is working in release but not debug that either means you are getting some undefined behaviour, or your project settings are incorrectly configured.

Comment: I use default project options except for the additional includes/libs

Comment: @Creysys If you want help, you need to do a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), than post it here. With the information that you have provided it is almost impossible to know what is going wrong.

Comment: ok, thanks i added a minimal, complete, and verifiable example

Comment: Does not work i already tested that :S

Comment: @Creysys I have tested it here, and, with `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` it have ran perfectly, without any problem. So, your problem is at your system, maybe, at compiler settings.

Comment: @Amadeus Try running it on release mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assert(!glewInit());
```

That isn't going to get compiled in Release mode.  So `glewInit()` will never be called and `glGenVertexArrays()` will remain NULL.

Calling a NULL function pointer generally won't work.

Comment: thanks, now i feel like an idiot trying out every compiler option ^^